# Getting System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'OfficeOpenXml'. Error message

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, visual-studio, ssis

I'm trying to import Excel sheet data into the DB via SSIS script task, I'm continuously getting the above error message.

The Excel file has 3 sheet, and we have separate table for each sheet of that Excel file in the database.

Also I'm not getting any error in the region Namespaces.

Can anyone help, what I'm missing here?

```
public void Main()
{
        try
        {
            string filePath;

            filePath = Dts.Variables["FilePath1"].Value.ToString();
            
            ReadXLS(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
}

public void ReadXLS(string FilePath)
{
    FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(FilePath);

    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        string eachVal = "";

        int wsheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Count; 

        for (int sheet = 0; sheet<wsheet; sheet++)    
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[sheet];
            string SheetNames = worksheet.Names.ToString();

            int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; 
            int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;  

            for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)  
            {
                string queryString = "Insert into [Billing_]" + SheetNames + "values(";
                queryString += "(";
                    
                for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)     
                {
                    eachVal = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value?.ToString().Trim();
                       
                    queryString += "'" + eachVal + "',";
                }
                 
                queryString = queryString.Remove(queryString.Length - 1, 1); 
                queryString += ")"; 

                runQuery(queryString);    
            }
    }

    private void runQuery(string QueryString)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source = ./; Initial Catalog = Testing; Integrated Security = SSPI;";
        
        string commandText = QueryString;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide `queryString` content from watch/debug menu? I mean what is the end result. It seems like your SQL is wrong.

Comment: Also: NEVER construct SQL commands from user input as this opens the gate for SQL Injection attacks, Use parametrized queries instead.

Comment: @Sebastian506563, Okay, Let me try with MessageBox. and let you know.

Comment: You say you're getting the error *"Incorrect syntax near 'OfficeOpenXml'. Error message"*, however, the phrase `OfficeOpenXml` isn't anywhere in your code.

Comment: @KlausGütter but is looks like tooling thing where it is ok

Comment: @Simma Just run program with F5 in visual studio and put "breakpoint" at (reddot) `runQuery(queryString);` then right click and pick "quickwatch"

Comment: @Sebastian506563 If you are 100% sure that the Excel files to process can never contain `';  DROP TABLE Users --`

Comment: I assume you have used nuget to add the EPPlus library to a script task (and thus the OfficeOpenXml issue). Nuget packages do not persist across closing the SSIS Script Task/Component editor session. They do not get serialized into the binary the package stores no does the execution engine know how to retrieve the libraries from the nuget package store. The only option is to have the assemblies installed into the global assembly cache, GAC.

Comment: Also, this code is likely not going to work `[Billing_]" + SheetNames + "`  At a minimum, you're missing a period in there. `[Billing_]." + SheetNames` would evaluate to Billing_ schema and and a table name of the sheet name. Most likely, you were trying to use the default schema and make a table name of Billing_ sheet name which would be `[Billing_" + SheetNames + "]` As you're working with Sheet Names and not named ranges, you'll then have a $ appended to the sheet name so the final table name would be `Billing_Sheet1$` As long as that's what you're expecting, all is good

Comment: You've got SQL injection all over this, **use parameters**

Comment: @Simma, SSIS has **Excel Source Adapter**. You could use is instead of SSIS Script Task.